# Assembly Language equivalent to Ceil , Floor

Tags: assembly, x86, floor, ceil, x87

What is the x86 equivalent of ceil , floor ? 
I can't particularly google the corresponding instructions .
The equivalent may not necessarily be a one instruction though one instruction would be preferred.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Math.h library functions in assembly x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762079/math-h-library-functions-in-assembly-x86)

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But I was looking something which the FPU could handle for example it has function for truncating and rounding floating points . I was looking for something in the similar lines .

Comment: Which FPU do you use? The x87 FPU or the SSE FPU?  The answer is going to be different depending on what FPU you want to use.

Comment: I am using the x87 FPU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-instruction floor/ceil is only available with SSE4.1 `roundsd` / `roundpd`, and only for XMM not legacy x87.

---

**With x87, you set the current rounding mode  and then use [`frndint`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/frndint)**.  (http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap1.htm shows where the RC bits are in the x87 control word).  The available rounding modes are nearest-even (default), towards +Inf (ceil), towards -Inf (floor), and towards zero (trunc).

Don't forget to set the rounding mode back when you're done.

Apparently `frndint` is slow on some CPUs (https://agner.org/optimize) so it can actually be faster to convert to integer and back with `fistp` / `fild` (still with the rounding mode set appropriately).  But that only works for FP values that can be represented as a signed 64-bit integer (assuming you use a qword memory operand).  You can instead add / subtract an appropriate magic number (to make the value really large forcing rounding).  Again, that may require setting the rounding mode.

**Of course if you *want* `(int)floor(x)` then definitely just `fistp` with the rounding mode set as desired.**

With SSE3, you can use `fisttp` to truncate toward zero (it was added to speed up C float->int casting in code that still wants to use legacy x87 even though SSE is available).

**`floor == trunc` for non-negative values so you could take advantage of efficient `fisttp` or SSE XMM truncation for that case.**

---

**With SSE4.1, for scalar `double` in XMM registers**, you'd use [`roundsd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundsd) to round to nearest integer-valued `double` with your choice of rounding mode specified by the immediate operand.  (Not a conversion, just double->double rounding like `frndint`, so it works for any value).  Packed and scalar single and double precision versions are available.

With SSE4.1, `roundsd` + `cvtsd2si` is your best bet for `(int)floor(x)`.  Or **if you know your value is non-negative you can just use SSE2 `cvttsd2si`**.  Note the extra `t` for "truncate".   (Same for single-precision, or for packed SIMD with `cvtpd2dq`.)